# Retrofit - Multiple Calls using for

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm kinda new to android developing.

I'm using retrofit to make requests, but in one case I have a list of objects that I want to add to a database, doesn't need to return anything really. So I tried using "for" to do this but it only adds the last object even though all the objects are in the arraylist and using the debug it goes through the "for" as many times as that are objects in the arraylist. Here is the code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(APIService.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                        for (int i = 0; i < horariosMarcados.size(); i++) {
                            APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
                            final Call<Horarios> requestReserva = service.reserva(horariosMarcados.get(i).getId_reserva(), numsala, horariosMarcados.get(i).getHorario(), horariosMarcados.get(i).getOcupado(), ReservaDetalhada_Popup.dia, processo, Login_Page.logado.getNome());
                            requestReserva.enqueue(new Callback<Horarios>() {
                                private static final String TAG = "reservaVic";

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<Horarios> call, Response<Horarios> response) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "TESTE: " + response.isSuccessful());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<Horarios> call, Throwable t) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Seu lixo!");
                                }
                            });
```

Is it possible to do it this way or do I have to use other libraries?
Many thanks!!

Regards,

Comment: are you sure that list has different entries? also sending your whole list in one go instead of calling service each time would be a good option.

Comment: Thanks! How would I do that? Do you mean just leaving the service outside of the for statement? Because I tried that but it also didn't work. Yes, I debugged it and it has all entries on the array list before going into the for statement.

Comment: change your service to be able to receive jsonarray. convert your arraylist to json array and send it over as request param.